# genymotion emulator not working properly on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-emulator, 64-bit, genymotion

Genymotion emulator was working fine but now its not working properly.

**My Setup:**

> Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
>
> Genymotion v2.5
>
> Virtual Device, Google Nexus 5-5.1.0-API 22 - 1080x1920

**System Configuration**

> Dell Inspiron 3543
>
> Intel Core i5-5200U
>
> Ram 4GB
>
> Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit

The problem is when I tap on something its does not respond until I maximizes emulator window or change its size.

Moreover, when i change window mode it changes to black screen. 
Also, emulator window pixels are distorted.
Need help in this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like graphic card drivers problem. Try to update it first and test again.

Comment: I couldn't find my graphics card drivers in the additional drivers but i installed them manually. After that i checked my graphics through this command in terminal: 

lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics [8086:1616] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
 
It says integrated graphics but i want to use dedicated graphics NVIDIA 
how to do that ?